# cache page before create fpdf

Tags: php, caching, fpdf

I need to show a new page after the creation of a pdf whit fpdf. My idea is create the page before pdf, cache it in browser, create pdf and than flush the cache and show page but I don't know how to do.

```
 <?php $txt = "hallo";
//My page to be cached
header("..........");
// my pdf
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(40,10,"$txt");
$pdf->Output();
// after pdf I want to show page in the cache
?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: do you mean to view the pdf in another page ?

Comment: No i need to load a new page. The real problem is that pressing the button to create pdf the data is saving in a database. If a person press two time that butto I have a duplicate record in my database. If after the pressure the page change noone can press two time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->Output("Filename.pdf","D");
```

The second parameter D in double quotes. This will download the file into the user's computer instead of saving it in your server.

I think this is the better way for creating the pdf. :)

http://www.fpdf.org[image]

Comment: I've try but the browser doesn't load the new page after save pdf

Comment: do you mean, a new tab window . ?

Comment: Not a new tab. I just want that pressing the button will be print the pdf and load a new page